# Python Menu Not Calling Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python and I've made a menu page which will call functions. It's for a coursework so it's all set out as questions ready for my demos. 
However, the menu displays and lets you input a choice for a question, but doesn't actually run the function? No errors, just nothing.

I've defined the functions in the same file, before I call the menu, and I've tried getting rid of the functions and just putting the script in the if statements, eg:

```
if questionChoice == 1:
    print("Hello")
```

But it still doesn't do anything? Here's the code in full:

```
def Q1():
    print("hello")

def Q2():
    print("hello world")

#MENU

def Menu():
    print("Question List:")
    print("Question 1")
    print("Question 2")
    questionChoice = int(input("Choose Question: "))
    return questionChoice

questionChoice = Menu()

if questionChoice == 1:
    Q1()
elif questionChoice == 2:
    Q2()
else:
    print("Choose A Question")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this via the command `python filename.py`?

Comment: Yes :( Still no luck I'm afraid

Comment: This is not elegant code, but it does work as you want I think, you do know that it's waiting for `input()` that you type before finishing right?

Comment: This works for me as well.  `Choose Question:` prints, I hit `1` and enter and it prints `hello`

Comment: It works now, thank you all!